# How do I calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{33}\binom{33}{k} k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I started studying about binom's and sums, How do I calculate
$$\sum_{k=0}^{33}\binom{33}{k} k$$

Note: I do know that it is $\binom{33}0\cdot0 + \binom{33}1 \cdot 1 + ... + \binom{33}{33} \cdot 33$, but how do I write it briefly?

Comment: Consider the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{33}$ and calculate the derivative at $x=1$.

Comment: Its not a huge leap to go to $$33\left(\matrix{31\\k-1}\right) = \left(\matrix{32\\k}\right)k$$

Comment: $$k\binom nk=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: Hint: Differentiate (1+x)^n in two ways.

Comment: i got this here $$141733920768$$

Comment: @vnd Still doesn't help.. (1+x)^33 = 33(1+x)^32 after derivation. and the binom has $\sum \binom{33}k 33x^{32}$ but I need $k$ in the binom.

Comment: @vnd oops. I had a mistake. thanks! i got it now! it is $kx^{k-1}$ in the binom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats a binoarithmetic series the key is to find the expression which has this general term so here its $(1+x)^{33}$ after this we do derivatives and plug in appropriate values of $x$ by trial and error method and then get the answer so its $$\frac{d}{dx}(\sum {33\choose n}.x^n)$$ where $n\in (0,33)$

Comment: Binoarithmetic series... what a nice description!

Comment: Am I right ? Because some days back my professor had taught me !!

Comment: Haven't come across the description before but it does seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{33}\binom{33}{k}k=\sum_{k=1}^{33}\frac{33!}{\left(k-1\right)!\left(33-k\right)!}=33\sum_{k=0}^{32}\binom{32}{k}=33\times2^{32}$$